# Error in Software Sources 404 Not Found

Tags: 10.10, updates, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I get an error while using `aptitude update`:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources              
404  Not Found

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages           
404  Not Found
```

What do i do to fix this?